# Accepting friend request MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Explanation:** As you can see I have two tables,
"user" and "Request"

- "use"r is my table which contains the id of the username
- "Request" is a table to record Friend Requests. When a user sends a request to another user this table updates with the ids of the "requester" (the person sending the request) and the "requestee" (the person receiving it)

**So my Question is**:
how would the action of a user accepting their friend request be reflected in these tables?

If possible, an explanation would be great or just to outline the pseudocode for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well how I would do it. Is either modify the request table to have a column status of the request and update that when it's accepted (or remove row when it's rejected). Or build a table friend that has id's of connections :

```
id_user1 | id_user2
   1     |   3
```

Comment: right, because you are really trying to get to the `junction table` rows (the third table that is the important one, not seen above), not caring so much about the request, which is more historical mumbo jumbo

Comment: you mean like i should add another column calling it `accept/reject`
and if some one accepts it `1` and when some one rejects it will be a `0`

Comment: @jake123 I would add the 3rd table.  And keep your request table only for requests. Having a 3rd table is so much faster to query. but yeah if you'd like to modify your existing one you can add column status : pending,accepted....

Comment: it's not so much what he would like to do. It is what is the right thing to do. Lean and mean friend table. Think how fast that would be with 2 composite int indexes